# combine matplotlib graph and sympy graph in one

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

i am trying to plot inequality functions and plot the point where this inequality connects, i have used sympy.plot to plot the region, but i can't plot the points in sympy, so i decided to use Matplotlib, but my problem is that i can't combine both, i know sympy uses Matplotlib for plotting, but it doesn't work .extend or append, my code is this, i really appreciate the help (and sorry if something is wrong written my english is not my best language)

I tried with .extend or append, but it didn't work, chatgpt says that plot_point exists, but sympy doesn't have this module, I have another code with matplotlib, however I love that sympy plot the inequalities with a line.

```
from sympy import *
x1 = Symbol('x')
x2 = Symbol('x2')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x')
y = sp.Symbol('y')

Funcion = 30000*x + 50000*y

x_vals = [0, 4, 0, 4, 2]
y_vals = [0, 0, 6, 3, 6]
Lista_Inecuaciones = [x>=0,y>=0, x<=4, y<=6, 3*x+2*y<=18]


#Grafica puntos en matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
puntos = ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, )


#combinacion para graficar en sympy
Lista_Combianda_inecuaciones = And(*Lista_Inecuaciones)
print(Lista_Combianda_inecuaciones)

#graficas
plot1 = plot_implicit(Lista_Combianda_inecuaciones, (x, -1, 10), (y, -1, 10), show=False)
plot2 = plot_implicit(sympify(Funcion), line_color="red", show=False)
plot1.extend(plot2)
#plot1.extend(puntos) #linea que lanza error, line that throws error
plot1.show()
```

Comment: "but it didn't work" may satisfy 'chat', but real live programmers on SO don't like that.  We want to see real errors - including full traceback.

Comment: From the error and associated code I see that the sympy plot object have a list attribute `_series`.  `plot1.extend` just does a list extend, adding the `_series` of `plot2` to its own.  `puntos`, is a different class, and does have such an attribute.

Comment: sorry, I recently read the comment, and my mistake, I didn't think to put the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sympy's `plot_implicit` accepts an undocumented keyword arguments, `markers`.
In this code block I'll add the points using this keyword arguments, specifying to use red color and a circular shape:

```py
plot1 = plot_implicit(Lista_Combianda_inecuaciones, (x, -1, 10), (y, -1, 10),
                      show=False, markers=[{"args": [x_vals, y_vals, "ro"], }])
plot2 = plot_implicit(sympify(Funcion), line_color="red", show=False)
plot1.extend(plot2)
plot1.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks man, in the end I did everything with matplotlib, but with this ,the code is simplified a loooott, really thanks <333